# how to use wp_query to display custom post type in bootstrap grid

Tags: wordpress, loops, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a template in Wordpress. I use advanced custom fields so my client can put in some information of his birds.

I use col-md-4 grid from bootstrap. The meaning is that i get 3 columns, with in each column the information of a bird.

Column 1 : bird 1
Column 2 : bird 2
Column 3 : bird 3

The loop doesn't work. It only shows the first bird. Can somebody help me out?

The code is :

```
<div class="container content">
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'stamboom',
'posts_per_page' => -1
)
);
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php 
$image = get_field('foto_duif');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $image ) {
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}
?>
<h3>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_field('naam_duif'); ?>
</a>
</h3>
<p><?php the_field('nr_duif') ;?></p>
<P><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Bekijk de stamboom</a></P>
</div><!--End col-md-4-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div><!--End row-->
</div><!--End container-->
```